# Random CSS behaviour

Tags: css, webkit

I'm creating an application that makes use of cool CSS3 buttons.
The problem is happening on android browser only, but since it is a web application for mobile phones this graphical issue is very important...
What happens is that buttons are displayed sometimes correctly, and sometimes in a strange way as you can see in the picture below:

[image]

```css
button {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  height: 2.5em;
  border-width: 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px 0px #696969;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px 0px #696969;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px 0px #696969;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #4e4e4e), color-stop(1, #2c2c2c));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4e4e4e 5%, #2c2c2c 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4e4e4e 5%, #2c2c2c 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4e4e4e 5%, #2c2c2c 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4e4e4e 5%, #2c2c2c 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4e4e4e 5%, #2c2c2c 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#4e4e4e', endColorstr='#2c2c2c', GradientType=0);
  background-color: #4e4e4e;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #474747;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0em 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px #000000;
}
```

```html
<button>Log-in</button>
<br />
<button>Email registration</button>
```

I cannot understand the reason why this happens! Do you have any idea?

Comment: Please include your markup as well. You also have a ton of redundant or repeated CSS above, and probably some unnecessary stuff (we haven't needed to prefix `border-radius` for like four years now).